# CakePHP subqueries to find using drop down box

Tags: cakephp, subquery

I have 2 tables Record and Genre and I need to filter the records table down by the Genre I select in the drop down.

The SQL I have is a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE genre_id = (SELECT id FROM genres WHERE genre = 'Blues');
```

How can I add this into my `RecrodsController` using latest `cakephp`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->Records->find('all')->where([
        'genre_id IN' => $this->Genres->find('all')->select('id')->where([
            'genre' => 'Blues'
        ])->extract('id')->toArray()
    ]);
```